# Would it be possible to indirectly kill people?

Tags: death-note

When John Zeärtö would write: Johnny Riler Accident. Tomorrow Johnny Riler will receive a piece from the death note. He writes the true name from the person who uses the alias Xavier. Would that work? (And yes Johnny knows the true name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario is totally possible. As long the 2 main factors can be reached.

1. *This note will not take effect unless the writer has the person's face in their mind when writing his/her name. Therefore, people sharing the same name will not be affected.*
2. *The conditions for death will not be realized unless it is physically possible for that human or it is reasonably assumed to be carried out by that human.*

So if he knows the real name, and can bring the face of the person to mind. And it is physically possible for that person to obtain a piece of death note and write in it. Then yes it is possible indeed.

Answer (score 1):

> Whether the cause of the individual's death is either a suicide or
>   accident. If the death leads to the death of more than the intended,
>   the person will simply die of a heart attack. This is to ensure that
>   other lives are not influenced.

I'm sorry but I don't think Dimitri is correct.  This appears to be the same as telling L's bodyguards to shoot L. This does not work. There are quite a bit more than just those two rules.

Comment: I thin it could work because i only wrote, that Johnny Riler writes the name of the man who uses the alias Xavier. I didn't wrote Johnny Riler kills Xavier by writing his name on a scrap from the death note.

Comment: Wording is never really the point of the Deathnote.  The search for loopholes does get tiring. Saying "shoot L" and "kill L by shooting him" are both not allowed. The only way to answer this question for sure it to get ahold of the deathnote and try it.  Light used this tactic to kill the Feds. He made the director send the names.  He coerced one Fed to write them in the book.  He had to coerce him, not order him via the death note.  Again, if this obvious loophole existed, he would have used it. Unlike us, he had the opportunity and will to try it out.

Comment: I do believe one of the rules indeed states that the users death may not be the intermediate cause of death. So if you were to write down somebody controlling a plane, he will die without people being injured. But I don't believe that rule also covers the fact that you can use the human to kill before making him die himeself.

Comment: The exact rule is above! I dont doubt that if you wrote both names, you could make them kill each other. If the persons name isnt in the deathnote, however, there is nothing to support the claim that he could be killed by a me5hod of death for some one else. The rule explicitly contradicts that. The question whether you can use the deathnote to make someone else write in the deathnote is debatable but not the claim you just made.